# Are Kubernetes updates an atomic transaction?

Tags: kubernetes

I wonder how Kubernetes executes updates. Let's say that two entities perform an update at the same time. How will the configuration be applied? Is applying/deleting configuration and in general performing mutations over K8S API an atomic operation? Is it possible to perform a mutation based on a condition?

Let's take this simple ConfigMap for an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testmap
data:
  foo: "1"
```

I'd like to update this configuration by setting `foo: "2"` but only if the `foo: "1"` exists in the ConfigMap. Such atomic features can be found in databases like MongoDB (e.g. findAndModify), Redis, etc. How can I achieve atomicity in K8S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kubernetes you will need to communicate with [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) to view resources or make changes to them.

`kube-apiserver` is using `etcd` as a place to store data required by Kubernetes.

> etcd is a consistent and highly-available key value store used as Kubernetes' backing store for all cluster data
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: Operating etcd clusters for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/)*

You can read on the official site of `etcd`:

- *[Etcd.io: Docs: v3.3.12: Learning: API Guarantees](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3.12/learning/api_guarantees/)*

> ### etcd specific definitions
>
> #### Operation completed
>
> An etcd operation is considered complete when it is committed through consensus, and therefore “executed” – permanently stored – by the etcd storage engine. **The client knows an operation is completed when it receives a response from the etcd server.** Note that the client may be uncertain about the status of an operation if it times out, or there is a network disruption between the client and the etcd member. etcd may also abort operations when there is a leader election. etcd does not send abort responses to clients’ outstanding requests in this event.

> ### Guarantees provided
>
> #### Atomicity
>
> **All API requests are atomic; an operation either completes entirely or not at all**. For watch requests, all events generated by one operation will be in one watch response. Watch never observes partial events for a single operation.

As you can read above, `etcd` has a guarantee to be consistent.

---

More information about the operations on resources can be found in this blog post:

- *[Blog.atomist.com: Kubernetes apply replace patch](https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-apply-replace-patch/)*

You can read there (blog post is quite lengthy but explanatory):

> There may be certain instances when you want to be sure that no changes have been made to a resource between the time you read the resource and when you are updating it. Put another way, you need to make sure all changes to a resource are *atomic*. This is the use case for updating a resource using replace. For example, if you have a ConfigMap with a counter that is updated by multiple sources, you may want to make sure that two sources do not attempt to update the counter simultaneously, causing you to “lose” an update.
>
> <-- SKIPPED -->
>
> The spec supplied in the replace request should be the fully formed resource spec, not a partial spec and not just the parts required when using kubectl apply. In particular, you must include the current `resourceVersion` in the [spec metadata](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/?_ga=2.88369363.992912871.1608821194-77209863.1608821194#objectmeta-v1-meta). If you do not include the `resourceVersion` or the version you provide is not the current one, the replacement will be rejected.

---

Additional resources:

I found similar case on Stackoverflow which is also dealing with similar question:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Are Kubernetes API calls secret update and configmap update atomic calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529204/are-kubernetes-api-calls-secret-update-and-configmap-update-atomic-calls)*

Comment: Thanks! I think I was looking for the "replace" command.